# SFTP with Paramiko saying my local path is wrong and permission issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

This should be an easy one for a seasoned programmer but being that I am still learning I am struggling a bit. I have created a script to sftp to a netscaler device and copy over the config file to my local computer. I am getting a localpath, path error and a permissions error even though I open pycharm in admin mode. Any insight and maybe a link to learn more about sftp clients in python would be appreciated.  The erros I am getting are "with open(localpath, path) and with open(localpath, 'rb') as f1: and (permissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: C:). I moved the path to C: because the IDE would not take the path to my documents folder. I also took out import sys as it said it was not needed. Thank you. Hopefully I will find a good book this weekend that will have my answers.

```
import paramiko

host = "10.x.x.x"                    #hard-coded
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport(host, port)

username = "put username"                #hard-coded
password = "put password"                #hard-coded
transport.connect(username=username, password=password)

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)


path = "./root/flash/nsconfig/ns.conf"    #hard-coded
localpath = 'C:'
sftp.put(localpath, path)

sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *download* a file, you have to use [`get`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.get), not `put`.

And you have to use a full path to a target file, not only a path to a target folder.

```
sftp.get("./root/flash/nsconfig/ns.conf", "C:\\ns.conf")
```

---

*(the `.` in front of `/root` seems suspicious too)*

Comment: Ok I did that but now its highlighting the "\n" in the "C:\ns.conf" and is saying "Invalid argument: 'C:\ns.conf' "

Comment: hhmmm Now its highlighting the two back slashes. But it did copy the file, just with nothing in it though.  Errors are as followed. I really do not care much about fixing all the errors, just the file not grabbing the bits inside.

Comment: file_size = self.stat(remotepath).st_size  
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file

Comment: Are you sure about the path? As I've already wrote, the `./root` seems suspicious. How do you see the file in a standalone SFTP client?

Comment: I removed the "." but it through a sftp.get(path, localpath) error this time. I just copied the netscaler path using the winSCP application. I need to download over 40 netscaler configs and to not want to use winSCP.  The netscalers have there own SFTP servers on them.

Comment: size = self.getfo(remotepath, fl, callback)

Comment: file_size = self.stat(remotepath).st_size

Comment: Show us WinSCP screenshot.

Comment: Ayyy! :D I guess when you log in you are already root, so the directory is /flash/nsconfig/ns.conf  The folder path shows root as the first directory but removing it fixed it! Thank you so much for your time and contributing to my knowledge!